# Crop a 3D image

Tags: image, matlab, 3d

I have an image of size *512*-by-*614*-by-*196*, with *196* bands or channels.
I want to crop it to a *50*-by-*50*-by-*196* sub-image,
I used `imcrop` but the result is a sub-image that is *50*-by-*50*. How can I crop the original image to be *50*-by-*50*-by-*196*?

Comment: Do you know which *50*-by-*50* section you want to crop out? Or are you looking for an algorithm to automatically detect that for you? Becuase it's a trivial thing to crop a matrix if you know which section you want, just use subscript indexing

Comment: I might add that subscript indexing works like this in your case: You can crop a 3-D-matrix M using the colon syntax `D_cropped=D(1:50,1:50,:)`, where you can use any range "start:end" for "1:50".